# Hyper-V, Linux Mint ISO "not UEFI compatible"

Tags: linux-mint, uefi, iso-image, hyper-v

I downloaded the [Linux Mint 18.1 32-bit ISO](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=225) and trying to boot a virtual machine from it in Windows 10 Hyper-V. I [verified](https://linuxmint.com/verify.php) the hash and signature of the ISO. I turned off Secure Boot in the VM settings. Now I get the following  message:

```
Virtual Machine Boot Summary
1. SCSI DVD (0,1) No UEFI-compatible file system was found.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Mint 18.1 does not have UEFI support in it's 32-bit ISO, only the 64-bit ISO, since hardware that only supports 32-bit does not support UEFI. There is no need for a 32-bit OS in 99% of cases, unless you have hardware restricted to 32-bit... Use a 64-bit OS in all cases, not only will it give you what you need but many applications are only being supported as 64-bit applications and the 32-bit versions are being gradually mothballed.

Comment: @acejavelin Thank you. This was meant to be a test drive to find an OS to install on the old 32-bit machine of a relative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Only 64-bit Mint ISOs](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3080) include UEFI support. Try the 64-bit version first. If you must use a 32-bit OS, then re-create the VM selecting "Generation 1", which uses PC BIOS instead of UEFI.